# When I'm trying to run this query I keep getting this error and I could not figure out why

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

1. This is the DTO class

```
public class InvoiceCountValueDto {

    private String ackNumber;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date request_date;

    private String consignor_tin, consignor_trade_nm;

    private long total_inv, total_values;
    private String status;
}
```

2. Repo

```
@Query("SELECT new org.nic.eCST.web.dto.InvoiceCountValueDto(i.ackNumber,i.request_date,i.consignor_tin,i.consignor_trade_nm,count(c.invoiceId),sum(c.invoice_value),i.requestStatus) FROM RequestOnline i, InvoiceOnline c WHERE i.ackNumber=c.ackNumber AND i.tinNumber=:tinNo AND i.requestStatus=:status GROUP BY(i.ackNumber,c.ackNumber)")
    List<InvoiceCountValueDto> getTotalInv(@Param("tinNo") String tin,@Param("status") String status);
```

3. Error

```
`Error`

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [org.nic.eCST.web.dto.InvoiceCountValueDto]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, long, java.lang.String [SELECT new org.nic.eCST.web.dto.InvoiceCountValueDto(i.ackNumber,i.request_date,i.consignor_tin,i.consignor_trade_nm,count(c.invoiceId),sum(c.invoice_value),i.requestStatus) FROM org.nic.eCST.model.RequestOnline i, org.nic.eCST.model.InvoiceOnline c WHERE i.ackNumber=c.ackNumber AND i.tinNumber=:tinNo AND i.requestStatus=:status GROUP BY(i.ackNumber,c.ackNumber)]
```

I have double check the number of parameters and all the data types but still stuck

Comment: It says - you should have a contructor in the DTO class "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class". This constructor should take all required fields as input parameters. In the code, which you have posted, there is no constructor at all. So currently there is only the default one, provided by java, and default constructor does not accept any values.